# .net program to parse .doc file

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, docx, doc

I want to create an application which will be able to parse doc/docx files structure of this file is shown bellow:

```
par-000.01 - some content
par-000.21 - some content
par-000.31 - some content
par-001.32 - some content
```

content could be multi line and not regular. What I want to do is to put these content into database I mean for first record - `par-000.01` into `code` column and `some content` into text column.
 The reason why I cannot do this manually is that I have about 15 docs where each of them contains about 10 pages of paragraphs I want to put into my database.
 I cannot find any article how can i parse whole doc file so I believe it could be possible if i write proper regular expression. Can anyone redirect me to the article how I can do what I want- I can't find anything that suits me probably I am using wrong key words..

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: actually by now I can load file line-by-line and store it in string builder into variable. But this way using regex is not really efficient.

Comment: Why do you need a RegEx if you are already able to read the doc line by line? Just find the paragraph break and save it?

Comment: 15 docs 10 pages each.   What performance problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Perhaps the Docx library is what you're looking for? http://docx.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you have reasonable amount of data, 15 docs * 10 pages/doc * ~100 lines/page = 15000 lines this is manageable in a word document, and you did not say that this is a repeating data feed, i.e. this is a one-time conversion, I would do it using an editor that supported global find and replace and convert to a Comma Separated Variable format. Most DB I know can load a CSV file.

I know you asked for C# app, but that is overkill for time and effort based on your problem

So

1. Convert `'<start of line>'` to `'<start of line>"'`
   for MS Word with Find and replace
   find: ^p
   replace: ^&"
2. Convert `' - '` to `'","'`
   for MS Word with Find and replace
   find: ' - '  Note: don't add tick marks.
   replace: ","
3. Convert `'<end of line>'` to `'"<end of line>'`
   for MS Word with Find and replace
   find: ^p
   replace: "^&
4. Manually fix up start of first line and end of last line.

you should get

"par-000.01","some content"
"par-000.21","some content"

Now just load that into a DB using its CSV load.

Also if you insist on doing this with C#, then realize that you can probably save the text as a *.txt file without all of the Word tags and it will be much easier to take apart with a C# app. Don't get fixated on the Word tags, just side step the problem with creative thinking.

Comment: Yeah, just save it as text and parse it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate parsing of Word documents (.doc or .docx) in C# using [GroupDocs.Parser for .NET](https://products.groupdocs.com/parser/net) API. The text can be extracted from the documents either line by line or as a whole. This is how you can do it.

```
// extracting all the text 
WordsTextExtractor extractor = new WordsTextExtractor("sample.docx");
Console.Write(extractor.ExtractAll());

// OR

// Extract text line by line
string line = extractor.ExtractLine();

// If the line is null, then the end of the file is reached
while (line != null)
{
      // Print a line to the console
      Console.Write(line);
      // Extract another line
      line = extractor.ExtractLine();
}
```

*Disclosure: I work as Developer Evangelist at GroupDocs.*